# How to figure out which column names are illegal in ranger?

Tags: tidymodels, r-ranger

Here is a ranger call:

```
rf_fit <- 
  rf_mod %>% 
  fit(my_outcome_factor ~ ., data = data_train)
```

and the output:

```
Error in parse.formula(formula, data, env = parent.frame()) : 
  Error: Illegal column names in formula interface. Fix column names or use alternative interface in ranger.
```

How can I tell which columns are illegal?

I tried setting up a function foo() to debug:

```
foo <- function() {
  browser()
  ranger:::parse.formula(my_outcome_factor ~ ., data = data_train)
}
```

This function didn't help me much, because I don't know how to get a breakpoint in the right spot.

It's ranger version 0.12.1.

Comment: You could try using `janitor::clean_names()` to rename column names to legal formats.https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/janitor.html#clean-data.frame-names-with-clean_names

Comment: Love this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this error when mistakenly trying to feed ranger column names that start with a numeric.  Adding a character prefix solved it.